# To which extent will bitlocker affect my boot chain

Tags: linux, boot, windows-8.1, uefi, bitlocker

My laptop has the following setup:

- uefi (no secure boot)
- gpt ssd
- custom bootmanager (refind, similar to grub)
- leading to windows 8.1 (via windows bootloader) and a varying linux distro (via grub)
- boot entries for all 3 and more in uefi itself (default entry is refind)

I'm tempted to enable bitlocker on c: since windows is my main OS and it has sensitive stuff in it, and truecrypt and veracrypt don't work with uefi (yet).

What I need to know is how this will affect my boot process. Does bitlocker transparently wrap itself around windows without affecting my uefi boot selections and refind configuration (paths to .efi boot files), or does bitlocker essentially form another link in the chain that needs to be booted specifically, after which it will in turn boot windows?

Comment: Bitlocker isn't going to work well with a bootloader other then the Windows bootloader.

Comment: @Ramhound refind boots the windows bootloader (bootmgfw.efi) though. Does your comment imply bitlocker adds itself as an entry in the windows bootloader? That would make sense and clear up my problem.

Comment: On UEFI there should not be a problem as EFI System Partition is separate (it should not be encrypted). Windows boot manager can be chain loaded from rEFInd or GRUB. Windows boot manager "knows" how to handle encrypted (with bitlocker) partitions.

Comment: @snayob good enough for me :) Now write it as an answer so I can mark it for you :P

Comment: Oh by the way, how about stuff like rescue media? Does the install media (for repair installs and such) also know how to handle it?